# E901, or TokenError: EOF in multi-line statement on repl.it

Tags: python-3.x

I have been coding on a website called https://repl.it. 
PEP8 is returning an error at the last line:

```
E901, or TokenError: EOF in multi-line statement`.
```

I've tried rewriting the section, redoing the indents, and renaming variables.

-EDIT-
I've checked the indentations and if statements, so here is the new code. Its still pulling up the same issues. Note that I am not very good at code and probably won't understand what you mean right of the bat. I will also try to add comments into the code.

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
advList = ["Crawl", "Walk", "Run", "Sprint"]
atkList = ["[A] Punch", "[B] Kick", "[C] Magic"]
restart = 1
myHp = 50
zomHp = 50
battle = 50

#Game Over Screen
if myHp <= 0:
    print("YOU DIED")
    print("GAME OVER")
    quit()

#Endless Game Function
for i in range(0, reset):

    #Traveling Loop
    while battle > 5:
        print(advList)
        trv = str(input("How would you like to advance?"))

        if trv == advList[0]:
            sleep(8)
            myHp = myHp + 10
            battle = randint(0, 40)
        if trv == advList[1]:
            sleep(4)
            myHp = myHp + 5
            battle = randint(0, 30)
        if trv == advList[2]:
            sleep(2)
            myHp = myHp + 2
            battle = randint(0, 20)

        if trv == advList[3]:
            sleep(1)
            myHp = myHp + 1
            battle = randint(0, 10)

#Max Health Cap
        if myHp >= 50:
            myHp = 50
        print("My Hp: ", myHp)
        print('')


#Battle Sequence
    if battle <= 5:
        print ("A zombie  approaches!!!")
        sleep(1)
        while battle <= 5:
            print (atkList)
            atk = str(input("How do you attack?"))
            #Randomizes Hit Chance
            khit = randint(0, 2)
            phit = randint(0, 1)
            mhit = randint(0, 5)
            zhit = randint(0, 4)
#Kick Attack
            if atk == "B":
                dmg = randint(1, 25)
                if khit != 1:
                    print ("Your Attack Missed...")

                if khit == 1:
                    zomHp = zomHp - dmg
                    print (("The Attack Hits for %s damage") %(dmg))
#Punch Attack
            if atk == "A":
                dmg = randint(1, 10)
                if phit == 0:
                    print ("Your Attack Missed...")

                if phit == 1:
                    zomHp = zomHp - dmg
                    print (("The Attack Hits for %s damage") %(dmg))
#Magic Attack
            if atk == "C":
                dmg = randint(1, 50)
                if mhit != 0:
                    print ("Your Attack Missed...")

                if mhit == 0:
                    zomHp = zomHp - dmg
                    print (("The Attack Hits for %s damage") %(dmg)
#Zombie's Hit
            if zhit == 0:
                zdmg = randint(1, 10)
                myHp = myHp - zdmg
                print (("The Zombie's attack Hits for %s damage")(zdmg))
                print ("My Hp:", myHp)
#Zombie Miss
            if zhit != 0:
            print ("My Hp:", myHp)
#Zombie Dies
            if zomHp <= 0:
                print ("You defeated the Zombie!!!")
                battle = 50
#Round End
    print("Zombie's HP:", zomHp)
    print('')
```

Comment: `else zhit != 0:` is not valid Python code, and the line below is not indented properly.  Make that `elif zhit != 0:`, or just plain `else:` since that condition cannot possibly be false at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting an error on the line

```
File "<ipython-input-3-252d942b8c20>", line 82
if zhit == 0:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, I noticed that "zhit" should not be initialized to zero as this conflicts with the comparison operator. Secondly, it would be helpful if you could add comments to the code to understand the purpose of the game. As for the EOF error on pep8, the documentation for pep8 maybe helpful, EOF901 points to E901    SyntaxError or IndentationError. In Python, proper indentation is most important. I hope this helps http://pep8.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.7.x/intro.html

It would also be a good idea to copy this code to a text editor such as Sublime, Atom or Visual Studio and switch to debugging mode to step through the code line by line. I tried the code on Jupyter notebook and did not find this error albeit a different one.
The https://repl.it/languages/python3 site also has its own debug environment. Perhaps, that would help you identify the source of this error.